# How to recognise the word as a single word in OCR that end of the line with a hyphen

Tags: pdf, ocr, text-processing

I am using ORCmyPDF. How can I recognise end-of-the-line words that break with the hype? And remember them as one word.

1. This will increase my search result with that words.
2. It will make my PDF content copy easy.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, question should provide some code, as well as input examples.

Based on that I can't really help, but in general approach to solving this problem is through these steps:

1. Before detecting hyphenated words, preprocessing the OCR result is necessary in a way that you will do deleting any line breaks that are not followed by a hyphen. This guarantees that the hyphenated words are treated as if they were a single unit.
2. Merge hyphenated words: Search for hyphens at the end of lines to identify hyphenated terms. When you see a hyphen at the end of a line, merge it with the following line by eliminating the hyphen and the line break. This will combine the hyphenated words into one word.
3. Spellcheck the combined words (optional): If necessary, run a spellcheck on the merged words to guarantee their accuracy.

Example in Python:

```
import re

def merge_hyphenated_words(text):
    # Remove line breaks not followed by a hyphen
    text = re.sub(r'\n(?!\-)', '', text)

    # Merging of hyphenated words
    text = re.sub(r'\-\n', '', text)

    return text

# Example of usage (hard-coded v)
ocr_output = """
This is an example of a hyphenated word at the end of the line:
hyphen-
ated
"""

merged_text = merge_hyphenated_words(ocr_output)
print(merged_text)
```